# Selection sort example in mips

Tags: sorting, selection, mips

I was looking around for an example that used the selection sort method in mips but came up with nothing. I have read the wiki on selection sort but was looking for an example. If anyone has a link to an example algorithm or has some example code that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Google for "selection sort c". Then take any of the implementations you find and either translate it into assembly manually, or use a C compiler (like GCC) to generate the assembly code for you.

Comment: STFW. Google "mips selection sort", 3rd hit looks like what you want